# How to prevent subsequent click events of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a button `btnAdvSearch`, when it is clicked again after the first time, the displayed calendar gets stuck. So I need to prevent the further clicks of the button.

My code:

```
$('<button id="btnAdvSearch_' + uniqueNum + '" class="" title="Advanced                   Search"><span class="ui-button-text">' + btnTitle + '</span></button>')
        .appendTo($('<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane buttonHolder" id="buttonHolder_' + uniqueNum + '"></div>')
        .appendTo(this.element))
        .click(function (e) {

            debugger;
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            self._validateSearchForm();
            //Check the form validation using jquery validation engine
            $('#frmAdvSearch_' + uniqueNum + '').validationEngine('validate') == true ? self._submitAdvancedSearchQuery(self) : "";
        });
```

Comment: try `$(this).prop('disabled', true);` instead of `e.stopPropagation();`

Answer (score 3):

It's a button, you can click it as many times as you'd like to. Just prevent the default action or disable it after the first click.

So change your script after ".click(function (e) {" like this:

```
.one('click', function (event) {  
    event.preventDefault();
    //do something
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Please have a look at [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: @FC' : The handler is executed at most once per element using `.one()`. So it works perfectly for the `dblclick` too.

Comment: Are you sure that he want's to use the event only one time ? I don't know if he meant double click like two fast clicks, or just two normal clicks, only once in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
```

or

```
$(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

So that when he clicked  for the first time button goes into disable mode.

Do not forget to enable it if validation fails.

Comment: $(this).prop('disabled', true); is the promoted method

Comment: or even just `this.disabled = true`